# Automated S.O.S. game representation and extraction of game results

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

I am creating a Python program which takes the dimensions of a rectangle shape and creates a table through lists. Then it must find the total amount of available positions and fill half of them with the letter 'S' and the remaining with letter 'O'. My goal is to count how many times the 'SOS' word appears horizontally, vertically & diagonally through a cycle of 50 repetitions and extract the average number of the triplets.

My code so far,

```
import random
n = 6
m = 7
a = [[i * j for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if i < j:
            a[i][j] = 'O'
        elif i >= j:
            a[i][j] = 'S'

random.shuffle(a)
for i in range(50):
    for row in a:
        print(' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]))
```

Although I am not sure if my method so far is appropiate, I need ideas on how to create the counting structure for horizontal, vertical and diagonal.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a letter in a certain coordinate x,y and then search in a 3x3 block starting from that position, like so:

```py
for y in range(len(a)): #cycle through every line
    for x in range(len(a[y])): #cycle through every column
        if a[y][x] == 'S':

            #check if it will go out of boundaries horizontally
            if not x >= len(a[y])-3:
                if a[y][x+1] == 'O' and a[y][x+2] == 'S':
                    #this will execute if there is a horizontal SOS
                    print(f"found horizontal SOS at position x: {x}; y: {y}")

            #check if it will go out of boundaries horizontally and vertically
            if (not x >= len(a[y])-3) and (not y >= len(a)-3):
                if a[y+1][x+1] == 'O' and a[y+2][x+2] == 'S':
                    #this will execute if there is a diagonal SOS
                    print(f"found diagonal SOS at position x: {x}; y: {y}")

            #check if it will go out of boundaries vertically
            if not y >= len(a)-3:
                if a[y+1][x] == 'O' and a[y+2][x] == 'S':
                    #this will execute if there is a vertical SOS
                    print(f"found vertical SOS at position x: {x}; y: {y}")
```

When we are checking if the script will go out of boundaries horizontally or vertically we subtract always 3 because there has to be minimum 2 position to look horizontally, the `len()` method returns the length of the list so since it starts at zero we subtract one and then 2 more because we need those 2 spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one question. By using your code I am getting a IndexError: list index out of range. How can I control the boundaries?

Comment: @AndreasKreouzos the variable a has to be a list of lists, something like this: `a = [['S', 'O', 'S'], ['O', 'O', 'S'], ['S', 'S', 'O']]` because the first loop cycles through the lists and the second through the items in the lists

Comment: Ok thank you, I will try to see what I am getting wrong.

Comment: Hello there, your code works pretty fine but still can't figure out how to limit the code not exceeding lists boundaries.

Comment: @AndreasKreouzos I figured it out now, when checking in the 3x3 block if the starting position is the last it will try to go out of boundaries, a try-catch block or check for the index should fix the problem, I'll modify the answer right now

Comment: Thank you very much, I started my programming journey recently and I am trying to grow stronger. Definitely not an easy task but I like it. I will keep your advices and trying to apply them on future projects when possible of course.